# java7 drupal services XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Unauthorized: Access denied for user anonymous

Tags: service, drupal-7, xml-rpc, java-7

I have a java web start program that creates content on a drupal 7 site using xmlrpc services 3.
My code is roughly based on [this](http://drupal.org/node/1267522)  and it works fine on the following platforms:

linux x86 x64 (openjdk6-7),
mac os x64 (java6 x64),
windows x64 (oracle jvm x32,x64) from java6 to java7u4

As of oracle java7u5 up to java7u7 my code doesn't work. In u5 i got some strange jnlp exceptions and in u6 and u7 i get the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransportException: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Unauthorized: Access denied for user anonymous
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.getInputStream(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:94)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:152)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:158)
org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:147)
my.program.Drupal7XmlRpc.createNode(Drupal7XmlRpc.java:223)
...
```

However, if I do run the program from my eclipse IDE on windows, without the java web start my code works fine.
I don't know if it's some security regulation on the latest oracle jvms or if it's a bug that I should post.

A final note is that my jnlp file is based on [this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/jws/).

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I would like to point out that you should post some code to help us develop a more precise answer.

What kind of authentication are you using? Are you using **any** authentication at all? 
As said [here](http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/services-inside-and-out), this kind of problem happens a lot because people try to create a node without authenticating first.

On the other hand, if you have already authenticated before trying to create the node, this problem can also happen. This is (most likely) due to the authenticated user not having the permission to create a node of the specified content type.

Comment: Probably my problem is not described that well. On the second line I have posted the link to the code that I'm using and as you can see there It's a username/password authentication.
The problem is that if this code is compiled and run on a machine it is working fine. But, if it runs though a java web start on windows I get the kind of problems described above.